# excel vba - copy certain cells (as opposed to whole row) based on whether a certain cell has a certain value

Tags: excel, vba

Completely new to VBA. I basically copied the code below and I am repurposing it.. the code essentially selects a row based on whether a certain cell has a certain value.  eg. if K5 is "yes" then select the row "K5" copy and paste into a new worksheet.

I am trying to do something slightly different.  I want to select certain cells as opposed to the whole entire row - How do I do this

For example, If K5 is "yes", then select A5:D5 & K5 & I5??

Currently the below code below copys the whole "k5" row and pastes it in sheet 2 if there a "y" that appears in the cell "k5"..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Declare variables
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, lastRow3 As Long
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim RngToDelete As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Set variables
    Set sht1 = Sheets("To DO")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Ongoing")
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Done")

'Select Entire Row
    'Selection.EntireRow.Select

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
    lastRow1 = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow3 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With sht2
    ' loop column H untill last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("H2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "Not started" Then
            If RngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RngToDelete = Cell
            Else
                Set RngToDelete = Union(RngToDelete, Cell)
            End If
            lastRow1 = sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=sht1.Rows(lastRow1 + 1)
            '.Rows(Cell.Row).Delete

        ElseIf Cell.Value = "Closed" Then
            If RngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RngToDelete = Cell
            Else
                Set RngToDelete = Union(RngToDelete, Cell)
            End If
            lastRow3 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=sht3.Rows(lastRow3 + 1)
            '.Rows(Cell.Row).Delete

        End If
     Next Cell

    End With

    If Not RngToDelete Is Nothing Then RngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Update Done!"

End Sub
```

I tried to implement the below (ignore the actual cells being copied, the concept of multiple cells instead of the entire row is what im after - sourced from [Select multiple ranges with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294820/select-multiple-ranges-with-vba)), which seems to work if I use it on its own, but im not able or sure where to implement it in the code above to do what I want it to do.

```
set rng = Union(.Range("A84:B" & LastRow),.Range("D84:E" & LastRow),.Range("H84:J" & LastRow))
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: All of the values from the selected parts of the row should be pasted contiguously one one line in the destination sheet, including the cell from the next line (I6 in your example)?

Comment: @TimWilliams, sorry, I6 is a typo, should be I5, will edit.  But yes you are correct, that is what the code is doing / what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet, sht3 As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range, e, rngDest As Range
    Dim RngToDelete As Range, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set sht1 = Sheets("To DO")
    Set sht2 = Sheets("Ongoing")
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Done")
    
    For Each Cell In sht2.Range("H2:H" & _
               sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        
        Select Case Cell.Value            'check the row...
            Case "Not started": Set wsDest = sht1
            Case "Closed": Set wsDest = sht3
            Case Else: Set wsDest = Nothing
        End Select
        
        If Not wsDest Is Nothing Then     'any row to copy?
            BuildRange RngToDelete, Cell  'build up the delete range
            Set rngDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            
            For Each e In Array("A1:D1", "K1", "I1") 'array of cells/ranges to copy, in order
                With Cell.EntireRow.Range(e)         '#note Range() is *relative* to EntireRow
                    .Copy rngDest                                   'copy this cell/area
                    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, .Columns.Count) 'next paste destination
                End With
            Next e
        End If
    Next Cell

    If Not RngToDelete Is Nothing Then RngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Update Done!"

End Sub

'utility sub for building up a range
Sub BuildRange(ByRef rngTot As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngTot Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTot = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngTot = Application.Union(rngTot, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this @tim.  However I can’t seem to get it to run.  I get the following error: type mismatch.  This is against the ```case “not started”: Set wsDest = sht1``` particularly from the “:” until the end of the line.

Comment: Sorry typo in declarations - should be `wsDest As Worksheet`

Comment: Im not sure how i missed the typo either..i was too fixated on the contents of the error message i guess.  Il give it a go once im back at the office and let you know how things go.

Comment: thanks so much for your help.  I have some other functionality that i would like help with, however i think il have to ask it as a different question.  But on the off chance you get what im trying to accomplish.